# javascript focus() method change value

Tags: javascript, focus, innerhtml

I want to make cell behavior like in Excel. If I click on cell and cell's attribute `expression` is not empty I want to put this expression's value into cell and focus on this cell.

Code:

```
// In this point tdElm.innerHTML = 1
    if (tdElm.getAttribute('expression') != "") {
        tdElm.innerHTML = tdElm.getAttribute('expression'); //expression = '=1'
        tdElm.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        tdElm.classList.add('focused');
        console.log(tdElm.innerHTML); //print =1
        tdElm.focus();
        console.log(tdElm.innerHTML); //print 1
        return;
    }
```

My question:

Why is cell's `innerHTML` value changed back after invoking `focus()` method? How to fix this weird behavior? I need pure javascript solution.

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`focus()` method won't make any changes to element's value.

I think you may check focus event handler you created for that element.

Comment: You are right! I have focusout listener on td and than method for update table values. What a fail. Thank you for quick answer.